# How to install node-sass and gulp-sass?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm-install, node-sass

I have trouble with installing dependencies in my project. Gulp-sass version is 2.0.4. When I try to install with `npm install` I'm getting error 404 with node-sass v3.13.1. There is no link for it. I've also tried to insert source file of node-sass v3.13.1 but it's not working. I know the trouble is with link, but is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Did you checked the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#debugging-installation-issues) ?

Comment: Problem solved. I've installed newer version of gulp-sass 3.1.0. After that I was able to install all dependencies without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node-sass is a c++ bridge so particular versions are only supported for some versions of NodeJS. In this case, you are running a new version of Node, that older version node-sass doesn't support. Newer versions also provide better error messages for this.